# what is the difference between #include<> and #define""

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me the difference between #include<> and #define..I know #include<> is used to include header file and #define is used to define macros or constants ..Is it like they are not similar at all?

```
#include"abc.h"
#define "abc.h"
int main()
{
cout<<"Hello";
return 1;

}
```

Comment: What is there left to say, when you already know the difference?

Comment: The difference is that there is no relation except that both are called preprocessor directives.

Comment: #include is used to include header files. In contrast, #define is used to define macros (in particular, these can represent constants in the code, although that use is not recommended).

Comment: `#define "text"` is a syntax error. FFS, compile the code you post. Also, `void main` is invalid.

Comment: @xeo depends on your compiler/system. I work on an embedded system where `void main(void)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Daan: No, that is wrong. In C++, `void main` is _always_ incorrect, whether your compiler accepts it anyway or not (unless your program is running in a freestanding environment, in which case _this_ main function may be omitted and I suppose you're replacing it with another one.) `[C++11: 3.6.1/2]:` "_An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type `int`**, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined._"

Comment: @maddy Given the way you ask this, it's pretty obvious that your real questions are: a) What are header files and b) What are macros. Perhaps you should consult one of the standard introductions to C++ about these two concepts.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've seen multiple C++ compilers for embedded systems (my current compiler is only a C one) where they have a `void main (void)`. If that means the compiler is not C++ compliant, then so it be :-). It has no use either, if you return from main the processor reboots xD

Comment: @DaanTimmer: The compilers certainly exist, but they do not conform to C++, and this question is about C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include` as you said is used to include a file before the actual compilation.

`#define`  is used to define a Macro.. that is replaced by its value just before compilation

if you write `#define max 10`
then just before compilation all the occurrence of "max" will be replace by the number 10...

*Furthermore, you should refer to [this Wikipedia article on the C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).*

Answer (score 9):

#### Similarities

- They are both parts of C++.
- They are both inherited from C.
- They are both implemented by the *preprocessor*, which transforms your source code on its way to the compiler.
- They both start with `#`.
- They both contain an English word.
- They are both rendered in lower-case.
- They are both used in your [broken] sample code.

#### Differences

- What they do.

  - `#include` includes things
  - `#define` defines things
- How correct they are in your [broken] sample code.

  - Your `#include` usage is correct
  - Your `#define` usage is incorrect

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is a perfectly correct answer to a perfectly incorrect question